# Use image_xscale to slow down speed GameMaker Studio

Tags: game-maker

Using the image_xscale that increases every time an object collides with a certain object, how can I make its speed go down using the increasing image_xscale? An example would be in agar.io, where circles slow down as they get bigger. What equation using the image_xscale would I use for this?

I've tried things like this:

```
speed = image_xscale * -speed
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
speed = start_speed - image_xscale * k;
```

where `start_speed` is your normal speed, without slowing.

and `k` is value which will define slowing factor.

Also you can add `max()` for define minimal possible speed (for speed can't equal to 0):

```
speed = max(1, start_speed - image_xscale * k);
speed = max(1, 10 - image_xscale * 0.5);
```